# 'shared application' is private member of "cocos2d::ccapplication"

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

am using cocos2dx 2.2

i got this error ***'shared application' is private member of "cocos2d::ccapplication"*** when acessing appdelegate class variables.

my code for access appdelegate :-

```
  AppDelegate*  appdel = (AppDelegate*)AppDelegate::sharedApplication();
```

below variable in CCApplication.h is in public property.

```
static CCApplication* sharedApplication();
```

little confused where am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your AppDelegate Class Code like this..

```
class  AppDelegate : public cocos2d::CCApplication
```

From

```
class  AppDelegate : private cocos2d::CCApplication
```

Your CCaplication is Private property. u need to change that to public.